# blackberry application develpment

Tags: java, blackberry, cordova

Is java the only language available to develop applications for blackberry. Though i have
checked phonegap but its not properly documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, yes. Alternatively, you can develop web applications what will work on BlackBerry.

See [BlackBerry developers site](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a [BlackBerry Widget](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/devbetasoftware/widgetsdk.jsp), which uses Javascript instead of Java.  It's still deployed and installed in the same way as a native Java app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use HTML5, CSS3 and JS to create apps for BlackBerry using tools such as PhoneGap Build or BlackBerry WebWorks.

Here is a [new book in Amazon](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?t=co074-20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&asins=B006X4A1TM&ref=tf_til&fc1=000000&IS2=1&lt1=_blank&m=amazon&lc1=0000FF&bc1=FFFFFF&bg1=FFFFFF&f=ifr) that provides a PhoneGap Build example that was targeted on BlackBerry OS 6.0 devices.